# What is this called and best practices of UI/UX?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, interface, human-interface-guideline

What are best practices for settings (UI) like this? I am looking to find out more about good practices, good UI/UX for this component for removing, adding items to different profiles (profile 1 has different added items than profile 2). Are there any good examples of UI/UX design for this?

[image]

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/word2007_2010/images/word_options/customize_tab.gif

Answer (score 0):

How many elements are you dealing with? What do you mean by 'Profiles'?

Knowing more about your current context will help with deciding what will work best. Elaborate or show more of your problem and I'll update as I can to be more helpful to your specific situation.

**The example you provided is using a [list builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_builder) to customize a toolbar.**

The list builder can be a helpful element. There are some alternatives.
Some mac os software instead allows you to directly drag, drop and reposition element on a toolbar directly:

[image]

The advantage here is you don't have a disconnect between the current elements and their position, and what you can add and reposition: it's right in front of you.

Comment: Its not about my elements, i am asking this in general. If there any redesign in UX or UI of this adding and removing elements like it is in picture of my post. You have some different commands, different elements to add them on that choosen command and on the lest there are some sections. My question is more on general because through searching (for curiosity) through google i didnt find even 1 redesign of this on UX or UI perspective, all pictures are from old UI and same principle.

Comment: I see...I've found that the toolbar customization that MacOS uses above to be very clear, because you see the consequences of your actions as you go...